# join только одной колонки по условию

Tags: python, pandas

Первый фрейм:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'column1': ['name1', 'name2', 'name3'],
                   'column2': ['condition_1', 'condition_2', 'condition_3']})
```

Второй фрейм:

```
df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'column1': ['name1', 'name2', 'name3','name3'],
                     'condition_1': [1000, 2000, 3000, 3000],
                     'condition_2': [10000, 20000, 30000, 30000],
                     'condition_3': [100000, 200000, 300000, 300000]})
```

Итог первый:

```
  column1      column2
0   name1  condition_1
1   name2  condition_2
2   name3  condition_3
```

Итог второй:

```
  column1  condition_1  condition_2  condition_3
0   name1         1000        10000       100000
1   name2         2000        20000       200000
2   name3         3000        30000       300000
3   name3         3000        30000       300000
```

**Задача:**
В первый фрейм данных в колонку `Result` записать значения из второго фрейма, по условию:

- значение из `column1` первого фрейма = значению из `column1` второго фрейма
- значение из `column2` первого фрейма = колонка с соответствующим названием второго датафрейма
- во втором фрейме намеренно задублированно `name3`, просто удалить дубликаты через `drop` я не могу по условия задачи, нужно просто взять первое совпадение, пропустив остальные

Хочу получить итог:

```
  column1      column2   Result
0   name1  condition_1     1000
1   name2  condition_2    20000
2   name3  condition_3   300000
```

Мое не работающее решение:

```
df_2.loc[:, :'condition_1']
df.loc[(df['column1']  == 'name1'), 'Result'] = df.join(df_2.set_index('column1'), on='column1')
```

Получаю такую ошибку:

> cannot reindex from a duplicate axis

Comment: `просто удалить дубликаты через дроп я не могу по условия задачи` - можно об этом подробнее? Почему нельзя удалить полные дупликаты из `df_2`?

Comment: в моей задаче есть несколько ДФ которые в дальнейшем используются для других операций и там уже используются другие столбцы, в сцепке с которым полного дубля не выйдет

пытаюсь находить решения без размножения датафреймов

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
res = (df
       .merge(df_2
              .drop_duplicates()
              .set_index("column1")
              .stack()
              .reset_index()
              .rename(columns={"level_1":"column2"})))
```

результат:

```
In [112]: res
Out[112]: 
  column1      column2       0
0   name1  condition_1    1000
1   name2  condition_2   20000
2   name3  condition_3  300000
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df['res']= df_2.loc[~df_2['column1'].duplicated(keep='first')]
    .set_index('column1')
    .lookup(df['column1'], df['column2'])

>>> df
       
  column1      column2     res
0   name1  condition_1    1000
1   name2  condition_2   20000
2   name3  condition_3  300000
```

Comment: Спасибо! Работает!
А можно уточнить про назначение "~" при локе df_2,
не могу понять, для чего и что дает

Comment: посмотрите df_2['column1'].duplicated(keep='first') и ~df_2['column1'].duplicated(keep='first') думаю, всё будет понятно